# Algorithm to return a list of objects based on rules/restrictions

Tags: .net, algorithm, search, filtering

I have a list of N items.
Each item has a monetary value.
Each item can be one of 3 brands and each item can be one of 2 styles.

I want to create an algorithm in which a user can set a specific amount they want to spend and set the percentage of each brand and body style they would prefer to create a list of items that meet all the criteria.

For example, I would like to spend 50,000 dollars on TVs. I would like 20% to be Sony, 50% to be Visio, and the remaining 30% to be Samsung. I would like 75% of them to be at least 50" and the other 25% to be under 50". There's also a hard limit percentage. So while I would like 20% Sony, I may set the hard limit at 25% to allow leeway and make it possible to resolve a solution.

I'm looking (preferably) for an equation that is scalable to add new restrictions easily (such as I want 20% to be smart TVs). I'm aware that multiple configurations will likely solve this equation, but there has to be a way of determining a best solution based on a given set of items to choose from.

I'm using .NET so high level objects and LINQ are gladly welcomed.

Currently I can only think to satisfy one requirement and run through all possibilities for the remaining variables and mark a hash table for valid combinations. This is time consuming and memory consuming, I would like a leaner algorithm.

Thanks ahead of time for any help :)

EDIT: To clarify what I would like help in is developing the logical flow (pseudo-code) to approach this problem so that I can put it into code. I understand that it is similar to the traveling salesman problem, but the complication comes in the adding of rules. I am hoping someone out there has the clarity to lay it out in a logical and step-wise approach in english. I can convert it to code.

Comment: Does it have to be the absolute "best" solution, or would you accept a "good enough" solution?

Comment: No definition of "best" and no guarantee there is a solution.

Comment: good enough works for now. But i would ultimately like to somehow score answers.

It should be possible to find a best though. It will be the solution that is closest to meeting the requirement percentages and closes to the desired total amount to spend.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for algorithms used for accommodating packages in a container or for the traveling sales man problem, given that your problem is similar to that.

A quick and dirty approach would be to go for the higher priced items, then fill the gaps with lower priced ones, this usually gives you a good enough solution; but if you want to have the absolute best solution, then you need to run all the possibilities and pick the best.

Comment: This is the current method im using. I use SQL to return me the data set divided by above and below 50%. then i brute force go through and add tvs until i meet the brand percentage requirements while always keeping track of the total.